# MS Business Contact Manager only accepts local SQL databases - but my server is remote - workaround?

Tags: sql-server

I need help/input with following situation:

Me and my business partner work in two different towns and would like to use Microsoft's Business Contact Manager as our CRM tool (please do not point to alternatives or other CRM solutions).

My test client computer has MS Office 2013 and MS Business Contact Manager (BCM) 2013 installed. The BCM demo setup worked without any issue - it installed a local SQL Server Express server and populated a database with demo data.

I do also have a hosted SQL Server 2008 from a hosting company. I created a database and a user within their webend and successfully connected to it via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

**The problem now**:
BCM only detects local databases installed on the client or on the local network - the setup wizard only asks for the name of the remote computer when I try to connect to a remote database (which has to be in the same local network). There are no fields for username, password.

So, is there any workaround in order to create "the illusion" of a local database instance which connects "in the background" to my remote server?

I read about aliases but it does not allow to enter a username and password either...

Hope someone may help.

Comment: Have you tried using ODBC to define a connection to your (remote) server?  Will BCM connect to ODBC sources?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I don't think an ODBC connection will be recognized - BCM only shows SQL Express instances. But I'd like to double check that - any hint how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the "BCM 2010 server wizard" (bing it/google it).  It is a free download from Microsoft.
There is a good description on winsite: 
http://www.winsite.com/Internet/Server-Tools/Business-Contact-Manager-for-Outlook-2013-Database-Tool/

Once  you have created the shared database, you can connect BCM to it using the connection settings.

```
File Tab
Business Contact Manager tab
Manage Databases button, Create or Select a Database
Connect to a Remote Database
Type the name of your server (or full web address)
```

I got these instructions from Microsoft's web site: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/connect-to-a-shared-business-contact-manager-database-HA010380203.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101810395

Comment: I do have the Business Contact Manager for Outlook 2013 Database Tool installed. It does not provide functionality for remote servers. With this tool you only can create a new database locally and do some other tasks like backup&restore ![Screenshot]([http://i59.tinypic.com/2gwfjfs.png)

Comment: The idea is to backup the local database and restore it elsewhere.  Once it has been restored elsewhere.  Read more on Microsoft's site  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-your-business-contact-manager-database-on-a-server-HA101810395.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link - it is exactly what I need, however I do not have admin access to that remote SQL server... it only has a weblogin where I can create SQL databases. Looks like there is no chance to create a connection without executing that BCM Tool.

Comment: You might be able to contact the tech-support from your DB vendor/host.  They are usually pretty accomodating for stuff like this.

Comment: The tech-support told me to create a DSN (data name source) (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)). Does anyone know how to set that up so BCM will recognize it afterwards?